# Running a webservice

Tags: .net, web-services

I have a web service created in .NET, now I want to test it but I am having problems. I setup everything correctly on Windows Vista. IIS. I keep getting "Not Found" every time I try to access it. http://localhost/myservice/service.aspx'
.NET framework has been installed too.

What can I do?

Comment: If you're getting "Not Found", how do you know you've set everything up correctly?

Comment: Is the virtual directory setup correctly? Permissions for that folder setup correctly?

Comment: to my knowledge they were. I followed instructions. but yes its clear something wasn't done right

Answer (score 5):

Try

http://localhost/myservice/service.asmx

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to go through:

1. On the publishing machine ensure that IIS is correctly configured to server ASPX pages (depends on IIS version, etc). Ask at ServerFault.com if you have specific questions
2. From the machine that the service is on go to the URL you believe the service to be published at. You should see a page giving you default information about the service. if your service only accepts simple inputs (strings, ints, etc) you should see a number of text boxes to enter the values. **If you dont see this page, the service is NOT setup correct and is not being served up**
3. Assuming that 2 worked without incident, If you have Visual Studio installed right click on your project and choose "Add new Web Reference" type the address of the service in and ensure that you get the WSDL definition returned from your service (it should look similar to the info from #2 above). If you dont have Visual Studio you can still put the address in your browser and verify that they page is served up correctly (if this is a different machine you cant see the "input boxes" but you will see the WSDL
4. Still in VS once you have created the definition, create a new instance variable for it and you should see (assuming you named your service "foo") foo. and foo.

If you can see it on the local machine, but not your dev box then there is a problem with the pages being seen by your machine, check the firewall etc (ServerFault.com if you have issues), if you cant even see it on the IIS machine then the service is not correctly deployed.

There is a basic tutorial for deploying webservices on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87h5xz7x%28VS.80%29.aspx).

I hope this helps.